# Не выходит ошибка «parsererror» в jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Моя цель увидеть состояние "parsererror" в функции обратного вызова.
"parsererror" говорит о том что данные приняты но сформированные с ошибкой.
Так вот я намеренно сделал ошибку в файле data.json - написал белиберду.
Например: {fgg-8f6+8} а "parsererror" не выводится.

```js
function fun(a, s, c) {
        console.log(s); // нету "parsererror"
    }

    $.getJSON('data.json', fun);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

```
$.getJSON('data.json', fun).fail(function(){ console.log("ERROR"); });
```

Comment: Оказ-тся fail замена error